# Handlebars block helper with noop 3rd case

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Calling `options.inverse(this)` causes a handlebars block helper to do its `else` block. How can I just have it do nothing? I have a situation with 3 cases and I want the non-number case to just do nothing. This doesn't seem to work. How do I do it?

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars) {
  Handlebars.registerHelper('example', function(test, options) {
    return typeof test != 'number' ? '' : options[test ? 'fn' : 'inverse'](this);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve 3 cases, you can nest another if block:

```
{{#if condition}}
    {{!--First case--}}
{{else}}
    {{#if someOtherCOndition}}
        {{!--Second case--}}
    {{else}}
        {{!--Third case--}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```